# Unable to create buckets

Tags: google-cloud-storage

After following https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/signup step by step, I'm unable to create any buckets.

Expected results:
Follow Guide, activate cloud storage, enter billing information

Reality:
When clicking on the Cloud console, I see "Invalid Credentials"
When I click create new bucket, once again I receive "Invalid Credentials"

I've logged off and on, waited a couple of days, tried different applications, but have not been able to use the cloud service.

[Billing Screenshot 1](http://bazaar.ackdev.com/images/Screenshot2013-12-26_08.36.48.png)

[Billing Screenshot 2](http://bazaar.ackdev.com/images/Screenshot2013-12-26-08.27.08.png)

[API Enabled Screenshot](http://bazaar.ackdev.com/images/Screenshot2013-12-26_08.40.10.png)

[Credential Failure Screenshot](http://bazaar.ackdev.com/images/Screenshot2013-12-26_08.40.40.png)

I'm currently using the file service which is to be discontinued at some point, so I need to get this working.

The account I'm using with app engine has been working well since the app engine beta many years ago, and I'm still being billed on other applications so I don't see a rhyme or reason why this isn't working properly.  I did go ahead and logged out of google, cleared cookies, cache etc and created a fresh account and still received same error message. Tried a couple of different credit cards as well. Using firefox, but did try chrome as well.

Thanks!

2014-03-30 Turned out I needed to use Chrome, unknown why Chrome didn't work on first attempt.

Comment: Please email gs-team@google.com

Comment: Hi, did that a few days ago and haven't received a response, any other ideas or contacts?  Thanks!

Comment: What does it say under billing status in your account?

Comment: For app engine deployment: Billing Status:
Enabled

Comment: For app engine deployment: "Billing Status:
Enabled", in Google APIs Console:  Billing

Enable billing to access the full set of services and increased usage limits.

Billing account: Billing Account for ---redacted---"  That links leads to billing, all looks well:"Dec 1, 2013 - Dec 26, 2013
No transactions for this date range
Nov 1, 2013 - Nov 30, 2013
No transactions for this date range
Oct 1, 2013 - Oct 31, 2013
No transactions for this date range"